# Progress-bar при копировании файлов

Tags: bash

Как на Bash можно копировать файлы так, чтобы была какая-нибудь строка состояния выполнения процесса? Например, как на `pip` или `git clone`.

Возможно, есть какой-то ключ для программы `cp`?

Answer (score 3):

В `cp` возможность отображения состояния копирования не предусмотрена. Вы можете попробовать утилиту `pv`. У нее есть особенности, про которые можно [почитать](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv).

```
 # pv file > /dev/null

 1.41GB 0:00:21 [66.3MB/s]       
 [=====================================================>] 100%
```

Comment: `pv` рекурсивно запускать нельзя?

Comment: @Dofri я с ходу не скажу, потому что ей не пользуюсь, но судя по всему, для рекурсивного копирования больше подходит `rsync`. Ну либо использовать `pv` с циклами, например `for f in \`ls\`: do pv ${f} > some_dir/${f}; done`

Answer (score 3):

можно воспользоваться программой *rsync* с опцией `-P` (опция `-r` — рекурсивно, для копирования каталогов):

```
$ rsync -rP /etc/vim /tmp/vim
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/vim
vim/
vim/gvimrc
            664 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=2/4)
vim/vimrc
          2,125 100%    2.03MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=1/4)
vim/vimrc.tiny
            662 100%  646.48kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=0/4)
```